# bash- Modifying even lines based on the next line

Tags: bash, awk

how can use awk to sum up the first field values from each two consecutive lines. I'd like to sum the first field of each even line k with the first field value from k+1, remove the odd line and replace the value with summation. Example:

file 1:

```
100 apple
200 green
300 banana
400 yellow
```

output:

```
300 apple
700 banana
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR%2{v=$1;n=$2;next} {print $1+v,n}' file
300 apple
700 banana
```

Comment: Thanks! what if I had more fields in each line and wanted to print all of those too? Do I have to use a parameter for each field?

Comment: Probably not, but you;d need to post some sample input and expected output in a question to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution

```
xargs -n 4 | awk '{print $1 + $3, $2}'
```